# How to update pg_opclass as non-postgres superuser

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm using poorly documented third-party software that does esoteric things with PostgreSQL 9.3.  At some point during its setup, it attempts the following:

```
UPDATE pg_opclass SET opckeytype=xxxx WHERE ...;
```

The statement is running as a database superuser (though not `postgres`), and fails with this error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_opclass
```

What permissions do I need to grant to allow this statement to work?

*Note #1*:  I tried granting all permissions on that table to no avail. 
 `\z` from `psql` reports the following (`zzz` is my superuser's name):

```
mydb=# \z pg_catalog.pg_opclass
                                 Access privileges
   Schema   |    Name    | Type  |  Access privileges   | Column access privileges
------------+------------+-------+----------------------+--------------------------
 pg_catalog | pg_opclass | table | =r/postgres         +|
            |            |       | zzz=arwdDxt/postgres |
(1 row)

mydb=#
```

*Note #2*: The exact same statement, when run as the `postgres` user, works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a (somewhat hidden) permission for users, namely whether they have permission to "update system catalogs directly," which is specified by the `rolcatupdate` column in the `pg_authid` system table:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-authid.html

This other answer talks about how to set it:

https://serverfault.com/a/300421

Anyhow, once I set it to `TRUE` for my user, the `UPDATE` was allowed.

That column in `pg_authid` appears to have gone away as of PostgreSQL 9.5.